# Intersect in JpaRepository

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have SQL query like below. I'd like to take the common  product_id,authorization_ids for certain merchantIds. 
In this example merchant 20000 has product1,authorization1 and product2, authorization1 whereas the other merchants only have product1, authorization1.

```
SELECT product_id,authorization_id  FROM ACQ_MERCHANT_PRODUCT_AUTH  WHERE merchant_Id = 20000
Intersect 
SELECT product_id,authorization_id  FROM ACQ_MERCHANT_PRODUCT_AUTH  WHERE merchant_Id = 20001
Intersect 
SELECT product_id,authorization_id  FROM ACQ_MERCHANT_PRODUCT_AUTH  WHERE merchant_Id = 20002
```

The query above gives the right result which is product1, authorization1.
I am trying to implement that in jpa:

```
@Repository
public interface MerchantProductAuthorizationRepository extends 
JpaRepository<MerchantProductAuthorizationEntity, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT new com.ykb.acq.application.sweep.util.ProductAuthMap(m.product.id, m.authorization.id) FROM MerchantProductAuthorizationEntity m WHERE m.merchantId IN (:merchants) GROUP BY  m.product.id, m.authorization.id")    
    List<ProductAuthMap> findIntersactionOfProductAndAuthorizations(@Param("merchants") Set<Long> merchants);

}
```

But this gives me more lines than the intersect. ( product1, authorization1 and product2, authorization2)

How do I get the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HQL not had intersect logic by merchantIds. In this, I count merchant_id groupped by (m.product.id, m.authorization.id) and if the count is equal the merchants count, then this pair(m.product.id, m.authorization.id) is in all merchant's Set.

```
SELECT new com.ykb.acq.application.sweep.util.ProductAuthMap(m.product.id, m.authorization.id) FROM MerchantProductAuthorizationEntity m WHERE m.merchantId IN (:merchants) GROUP BY  m.product.id, m.authorization.id having count(distinct m.merchantId) =:merchantsCount
```